# jquery v1.3.2 find element by attribute

Tags: jquery

I need to find and iterate through all child elements that have specific attribute. The following code worked fine in jquery 1.2.6, but throws exception in 1.3.2

```
$(parentElement).find('*[@someAttributeName]').each(function(index){
    doSomething(this);
});
```

What is the correct way to achieve that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just get rid of the @, I believe.

```
$(parentElement).find('[someAttributeName]').each(function(index){
    doSomething(this);
});
```

From the jQuery [selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) docs:

> Note: In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style
>   selectors were removed (they were
>   previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2).
>   Simply remove the '@' symbol from your
>   selectors in order to make them work
>   again.

Comment: The @ symbol was from the original XPath type selector, IIRC

Comment: any way of finding acording to attribue equals specific value ?

Comment: You can use a simple `$('div[someAttributeName]').each()` to find by attribute

Comment: @JasonPrawn - that doesn't do exactly the same thing as the OP had in his question.

Answer (score 2):

Note the "@" before the attribute name was deprecated as of version 1.2.

```
$(parentElement).find('*[someAttributeName]').each(function(index){
    doSomething(this);
});
```

Just remove it and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

`[@attribute]` notation is deprecated in jQuery 1.3. Remove the `@` sign and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

ithink this is the best way to find and can change something of it

```
   $('.youritem').each(function(){
                          if($(this).attr('title') == 'add image')
                                           $(this).attr('id','imageuploader');

                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work for me in IE when I want to find inputs with `required=""`.

Works when I change to `required="required"`. Maybe other combinations also work https://stackoverflow.com/a/3012975/588759