# Spring form tag and HTML 5 still incompatible?

Tags: spring, html, required

I am using a spring form tag

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<form:input path="name.lastName" cssClass="text" maxlength="30"/>
```

When I try to add the new required html5 attribute

```
<form:input path="name.lastName" required="required" cssClass="text" maxlength="30"/>
```

I get this error message when the jsp is converted to html

```
<pre>org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/admission/registration/patientForm.jsp(168,5) PWC6131: Attribute required invalid for tag input according to TLD
```

Are the springframework tags ready for html 5 ? If yes, how do i use them ?

I am using spring 2.5

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004703/required-attribute-html5

Comment: pradeek.. The thread you posted is not really related to spring form tags..

Comment: Ok so I researched a bit more and I found out that I need to upgrade to spring mvc 3.

Comment: @frozenfury you should add that as an answer and accept it. That way the question won't show up as unanswered and others will benefit from your insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I researched a bit more and I found out that I need to upgrade to spring mvc 3.

Comment: I don't believe Spring form tags has compatibility with the 'required' tag yet. If you look in the TLD it is not a valid input