# HTML 5 require either input fields

Tags: html, required

Lets say I have two input fields

```
<input id='intput1' type='text' />
<input id='intput2' type='text' />
```

Can I use the html 5 attribute required to specify that either input1 or input2 is required

Comment: The below link may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004703/required-attribute-html5

Answer (score 1):

Not as [currently drafted](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-required-attribute):

> The required attribute is a boolean attribute. When specified, the
>   element is required.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 adds a new attribute, `required`. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_required.asp) for details.

This doesn't solve your problem because it is just defined for one specific field and doesn't check cross-field.

```
<input id='intput1' type='text' required='required' />
<input id='intput2' type='text' required='required' />
```

If you want to have a more flexible way of checking this, I advise adding some JScript for this.