# How can I make a textbox readonly in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I make a textbox readonly in this code

```
<?php 
    echo form_input(array(
        'name'=>'price',
        'value'=>$item['price'],
        'size'=>'6'
    ));
?>
```

I want only certain users to only read the value and not be able to change it.

Comment: Be aware that in your form validation you'll still need to make sure that the content hasn't been changed by a disallowed user, as setting a html attribute can easily be undone by someone wiley.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try like

```
<?php 
  echo form_input(array('name'=>'price','value'=>$item['price'],'size'=>'6',
     'readonly'=>'true'));
      //Or 'readonly'=>'readonly'
?>
```

Comment: required="true" is not a valid HTML5 syntax, check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004703/required-attribute-html5#3012975

Answer (score 3):

```
$options    =   array(
                    'name'      =>  'price',
                    'value'     =>  $item['price'],
                    'size'      =>  '6'
);

if(!$allowed_user){
    $options['readonly']    =   'readonly'
}

echo form_input($options);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# Try pure PHP
if(isset($_POST['something'])){
# Do not set the readonly attribute
$readonly ='';
}else{
# Set the readonly attribute
$readonly = 'readonly';
}
<input type="text" <?php echo $readonly; ?>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with:

```
<?php 
  echo form_input(array('name'=>'price','value'=>$item['price'],'size'=>'6',
     'readonly'=>'readonly')); 
?>
```

This will be xhtml compatible.

Just be sure to **NOT** read it on server side, don't trust on client data, because HTML can be changed to allow to modify values.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this:

from CI form field:

```
  echo form_input(array('name'=>'price','value'=>$item['price'],'size'=>'6','readonly'=>'true'));
```

from jquery/javascript:

using id of the field as:

```
 $("#id_offield").attr("readonly",true);
```

in html:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" readonly>
```

etc!

hope it will help!