# HTML textbox required on button click

Tags: html

```
<b>Gebruikersnaam:</b><br>
<input id="textbox" type="text" value="" size="25" required>
<a id="googleLink" href="##klik nu om member te kopen##" 
 onclick="this.href='https://websitelink.com?naam=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('textbox').value);">
  <button>Koop: MEMBER</button>
</a>
```

I want: `<input id="textbox" type="text" value="" size="25" required>`

to be required when i click:   `<button>Koop: MEMBER</button>`

like: if `<input id="textbox" type="text" value="" size="25" required>` value=""

its shows an alert like: "No username entered"

Fixed, Thx Lepanto

Comment: Try using javascript to validate the content of the textbox and prompt the user to fill the missing field

Comment: This facility only available in HTML5 without jquery or javascript

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004703/required-attribute-html5

Answer (score 1):

You need to cleanup your code first.  not sure why you're using `<a>`.  Anyway It would be pretty good to validate using [**onblur()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)

**HTML code:**

```
<input id="textbox" type="text" value="" size="25" required onblur="validateTextBox()">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function validateTextBox() {
    if (document.getElementById("textbox").value != "") {} else {
        alert("Please enter a value");
    }
}
```

Check this out in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/fCrfy/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is no such thing as `required` attribute in HTML tag `textarea`.

You have to create your own validation methods using Javascript. One of them is [Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) (which requires jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a JavaScript function to validation the textbox. Something like below

```
<script>
function doclick(){
    if(document.getElementById('textbox').value != ''){
        this.href='https://websitelink.com?naam=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('textbox').value);
    }
    else{
        alert('No username entered');
    }
}
</script>
```

And call this function in your HTML  tag onclick

```
<b>Gebruikersnaam:</b><br>
<input id="textbox" type="text" value="" size="25" required>
<a id="googleLink" href="##klik nu om member te kopen##" onclick="doclick()">
<button>Koop: MEMBER</button>
</a>
```