# Grails Required validator not working in Safari Browser?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Grails **required field validator** is not working in  safari browser.

```
<g:textField name="username" class="drpdwn"  required="Enter data"/>
```

Comment: And working in chrome?

Comment: Yup.. in chrome.. mozila .. even in IE8 its working Fine

Comment: What is version of safari?

Comment: Maybe try to do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3012975/1815058

Comment: @baxxabit : still not working

Comment: Hi, could you please accept my answer if it's correct?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/697) in safari.

From discussion in github:

> The sad truth is, that HTML5 forms features are fragmented. Safari 5.0.0 has included very odd support for interactive form validation, removed it in 5.0.2 and hasn't done anything for Safari 6

Also there is a [ticket](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97085) for safari 5.1, created by Paul Irish

> This conversation is about interactive validation feature.
>
> Safari supports the required attribute.
>    -  correctly matches :invalid selector
>    - input.validity.valueMissing correctly returns true for 
>   But form submission is not prevented because Safari has no interactive validation feature.

And another [ticket](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=59019), which status **"WONT FIX"** and quote from there:

> We disabled the interactive form validation feature because the implementation was incomplete and there were some compatibility issues.