# Mobile Safari - Required attribute html5 support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

Does anyone knows how to make Required fields to work on Safari Mobile?

```
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="" required="required" />
```

I am using the HTML5 attribute for specific fields and I learned that Safari desktop didn't support this HTML5 attribute and I fix it using modernizr.com.

Is there a way to "fix" safari mobile version (and Chrome mobile). Opera mobile recognizes it.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks

Comment: please, do some research before you ask a question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004703/required-attribute-html5

Comment: I did and the link you post, does not help me, or I don't see the answer. Is there any way to make "required" to work in Safari mobile? Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, you have to implement checks for required fields using javascript