# Input required validation popups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, heroku

Basically I have a `text_field` in RoR application that has `required: 'true'`.

The validation works in both development and production, but for some reason on Heroku I don't get the popup for a required field. ("please fill out the field")

If I run the server locally in production mode every thing fine.

Any ideas?
Thanks :)

Comment: have you ran "rake assets:precompile"?

Comment: Are you asking about server side validation or client side validation or browser helpers(e.g. Firefox) for required fields

Comment: @Babar, yes I did ran rake assets:precompile

Comment: @engineersmnky, client side validation that has predefined popup when empty.

Comment: @Anton what if you try text_area instead of  text_field

Comment: Well.. I did "rake assets:precompile" once again and pushed to Heroku and now the popup work on Firefox and Chrome, but not Safari.

Comment: @WaliAli, on the same form I do have text_area.. same issue.
I found this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004703/required-attribute-html5
It is sad that required: 'true' is wrong.. should be required : '' or 'required'. 
Tried it.. no luck in Safari.. (Firefox and Chrome all good)

Comment: check for alternate methods, as there are some things that are browser specific, like the way safari treats numeric text fields, I am sure it has something to do with that, good to know that is started working on two of the browsers