# Button is auto disabled , gets enabled after a click

Tags: html, angular7

I am working with angular TD forms. There is a form field and a submit button. The button should be disabled only if there is no values in the form. Meanwhile, chrome saves the form fields value (Username and password saving in chrome), so there are still values in the form field.But the button is disabled . But it gets enabled after clicking anywhere in the web page. How to prevent this?

The following link explained the problem in jquery. How to do the same thing in angular 7?

[Enable button when browser fills data automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057284/enable-button-when-browser-fills-data-automatically?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Disable the autocomplete from your form as

```
<form action="/..." autocomplete="off">
```

for more info you can refer to [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)