# Required field on preventDefault()

Tags: jquery

The plan is to set id #required as required field on click.
This does not work:

```
 $("#submitformat").click(function( event ) {
 $("#required").prop('required',true);
 event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Comment: Have you tried using `return false;` instead?

Comment: $('#required').attr('required', 'required');

Comment: just don't understand why to add required parameter to element on click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think set required attribute is not good thing if you wan't to make any field to required then please see below J Query code

```
$("#submitformat").click(function(event) {
   var test=$("#required").val();
   if(test==''){
    event.preventDefault();
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#submitformat").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $('#required').attr('required', 'required');
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Using this even if #required is populated submit click does nothing

Comment: we don't understand why to do that trick? when You could just add element with required="required". so You wanted to add this param and I gave You resolution. :)

Comment: @num8er exactly :) accepted answer checks if there's required attr and cancels event, it doesn't even cancel immediate propagation :) What was asked is to add required attribute on click.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest returning false, it will prevent event from bubbling up the DOM tree, and required attribute is used like `'required' = 'required'` [and not 'required' = 'true'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004703/required-attribute-html5) . It might work on some browsers, but not all, also you should apply binding when document has fully loaded, best on `document.ready`.

```
$(function(){
  $("#submitformat").click(function() {
     $("#required").prop('required','required');
     return false;
      });
 });
```

Comment: same here if #required is populated submit click does nothing