# ASP.net Webforms HTML5 "required" not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, requirejs

I am quite new to ASP.NET, I am trying to use the HTML5 `required` attribute on a textbox.

```
<form action="/../.." method="post" style="margin-bottom: 20px;" id="testform">
      <input type="text" name="Username" required="required">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign In" name="Submit"/>
</form>
```

When i submit my form without filling the textbox with data, it doesnt show any error message:

When I inspect my form, i see a class has been added by `required`, but no error message shows:

[image]

The same code works fine in JSFiddle, Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Luthando/542qd8Lf/1/)

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004703/required-attribute-html5

Comment: I am using the latest chrome, its not a duplicate

Comment: What's handling the click event on the client?  Anything?

Comment: nothing, it is supposed to work without any event...i created a fiddle that work fine... look at it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Luthando/542qd8Lf/1/)