# jquery element: how to set required = "true" and NOT required = "required"?

Tags: jquery

When I do this in jquery:

```
$("#elementid").attr("Required", true);
```

it renders as

```
required = "required"
```

I want it to render as

```
required = "true"
```

any suggestions?

Comment: `$("#elementid").attr("Required", "true");`

Comment: Does `$("#elementid").attr("Required", "true");` do what you want?

Comment: @guradio 1 second difference nice

Comment: @JCOC611 that 1 sec diff in pressing enter :)

Comment: Why do you want to set `required = "true"`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3012975/459750

Comment: guradio & JCOC611:  $("#elementid").attr("Required", true); and $("#elementid").attr("Required", "true"); both doesnt work the way I want. It renders as required = "required".